# Windows 10 Tablet Mode without touchscreen

Tags: windows-10, graphics-tablet, tablet-mode

I don't have a touchscreen computer, however I would like to try tablet mode with my graphics tablet but windows doesn't let me activate it.
Is there a registry or something I can edit to enable tablet mode without having to have a touchscreen?

Comment: No; there is not